# ORA-01843: not a valid month when doing comparisons with to_date()

Tags: oracle

The query is here:

> http://pastebin.com/t8NsWa9a

I have a column of data which is USER-entered. It is supposed to be a date but the formatting is inconsistent. I have to convert this user-entered data to a date using to_date() so I can compare it to trunc(SYSDATE). The query runs fine without the last WHERE clause:

```
WHERE (CASE WHEN to_date(del_date,'MM/DD/YY') = trunc(SYSDATE+1) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) = 'Y'
```

The error I receive:

> [Error Code: 1843, SQL State: 22008]  ORA-01843: not a valid month

I read that the error code 1843 does not always show up even if an error has occurred. Anyone care to offer some insight on why this happens? I've searched around and could not find someone who is trying to do the same thing as I am. Thanks in advance.

Here is an example of the user entered data after it has been filtered by the query:

> http://pastebin.com/nTrgNGCW

If I create a table and select the query into that without the WHERE clause, and then from there I filter out where DEL_DATE = SYSDATE+1, it works, but I would rather not have to do that every time this query runs on a scheduled task.

Comment: Instead of linking to off-site resources you should paste the code and sample data here, but as the query is long, cut it down to a minimal working example that reproduces the error. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: del_date is varchar2 which is then converted to date format in the comparison with sysdate

Comment: Then somewhere in your data is a value that doesn't comply with the `mm/dd/yy` format. You could use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702050/valid-date-checks-in-oracle to validate your inputs