# How to find a specific mask within a string - Oracle?

Tags: string, oracle, date, mask, to-date

I have a field in a table that can be informed with differente values.
Examples:

```
Row 1 - (2012,2013) 
Row 2 - 8871 
Row 3 - 01/04/2012 
Row 4 - 'NULL'
```

I have to identify the rows that have a string with a date mask 'dd/mm/yyyy' informed. Like Row 3, so I may add a TO_DATE function to it.

Any idea on how can I search a mask within the field?

Thanks a lot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702050/valid-date-checks-in-oracle

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a data model problem (storing a date in a string).

But, since it happens and we sometimes can't control or change things, I usually keep a function around like this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION safe_to_date (p_string        IN VARCHAR2,
                                         p_format_mask   IN VARCHAR2,
                                         p_error_date    IN DATE DEFAULT NULL)
  RETURN DATE
  DETERMINISTIC IS
  x_date   DATE;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    x_date   := TO_DATE (p_string, p_format_mask);
    RETURN x_date;                                                        -- Only gets here if conversion was successful
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RETURN p_error_date;
  END;
END safe_to_date;
```

Then use it like this:

```
WITH d AS
       (SELECT 'X' string_field FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '11/15/2012' FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '155' FROM DUAL)
SELECT safe_to_date (d.string_field, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
FROM   d;
```

Comment: Can you add `CREATE OR REPLACE` in you ddl so that this could stand alone (as opposed to being in a package)? Also at least, remove that `END LOOP;` => the blocks are not right.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f43a6/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Test ( id, VALUE ) AS
          SELECT 'Row 1', '(2012,2013)' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Row 2', '8871' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Row 3', '01/04/2012' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Row 4', NULL FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Row 5', '99,99,2015' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Row 6', '32/12/2015' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Row 7', '29/02/2015' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Row 8', '29/02/2016' FROM DUAL
/
```

**Query 1 - You can check with a regular expression**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TEST
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( VALUE, '^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f43a6/1/0)**:

```
|    ID |      VALUE |
|-------|------------|
| Row 3 | 01/04/2012 |
| Row 6 | 32/12/2015 |
| Row 7 | 29/02/2015 |
| Row 8 | 29/02/2016 |
```

**Query 2 - You can make the regular expression more complicated to catch more invalid dates**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TEST
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( VALUE, '^(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/\d{4}$' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f43a6/1/1)**:

```
|    ID |      VALUE |
|-------|------------|
| Row 3 | 01/04/2012 |
| Row 7 | 29/02/2015 |
| Row 8 | 29/02/2016 |
```

**Query 3 - But the best way is to try and convert the value to a date and see if there is an exception**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_Valid_Date(
  datestr VARCHAR2,
  format  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'DD/MM/YYYY'
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
AS
  x DATE;
BEGIN
  IF datestr IS NULL THEN
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;
  x := TO_DATE( datestr, format );
  RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 0;
END;
/


SELECT *
FROM   TEST
WHERE  is_Valid_Date( VALUE ) = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f43a6/1/2)**:

```
|    ID |      VALUE |
|-------|------------|
| Row 3 | 01/04/2012 |
| Row 8 | 29/02/2016 |
```

Comment: I am partial to regular expressions too.  The failing with this is false trues like `99,99,2015`.  This will result in a false positive based on the op's requirement.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the like operator to match the pattern.

where possible_date_field like `'__/__/____'`;