# Oracle query with to_date() gets ORA-01858

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I am using the below syntax to convert a character field into a date within 'Toad for Oracle':

```
to_date(value_char, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American')
```

I receive the error:

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected'

I believe the error may be to single digit months and days. For example here are a couple values of the field:

```
3/3/2020 9:56:00 AM
12/14/2020 10:39:00 AM
```

Is there a specific syntax to specific no preceding '0'.

Comment: You don't get that error from that data - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6fa8f1e0609333a0f7dab6698a81322f). Though the NLS argument isn't doing anything. So it's something else in your query, or more likely other values in the column. The name suggests you might have different types of data crammed into one string field - maybe numbers, or dates in mixed formats, or invalid dates - always a risk with data stored as the wrong data type.

Comment: Thank you for the response. That field is used for other attributes as well and is sorted by a different category attribute. Originally, I had used a where statement to filter for the needed category. I have also tried a subquery (in the from clause) with the category specified but still receiving same error. Is there a way to partition the field to only the specific category to allow the use of to_date?

Answer (score 3):

You don't give a database version, but the following should tell you where the problem is if your are in 12.2 or later.

```
select value_char
from table
where to_date(value_char default null on conversion error,
          'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') is null;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Originally, I had used a where statement to filter for the needed category. I have also tried a subquery (in the from clause) with the category specified but still receiving same error.

Oracle won't necessarily apply all filters before attempting data conversions; particularly if you are using that converted date value within a filter/join condition.

Fortunately [case expressions use short-circuit evaluation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html), so you can use one to restrict when the conversion is attempted:

```
case when value_type = 'DATE' then
  to_date(value_char, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
end
```

... where `value_type = 'DATE'` is whatever category check you would use to identify a row that holds a suitable value - and then you still have to hope you don't have malformed data, of course, but that's the cost of storing everything as strings.

If you're on 12cR2+ then @Gary's suggestion to use [the `to_date()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html) `on conversion error` clause with would also work - on it's own, or combined with this so it's only catching malformed values.

Comment: Hello Alex, Thank you for the response. I do not believe I am on 12cR2 as Gary's statement does not work.  I am able to successfully run the query with the case statement, however it also returns the other category attributes with a blank value. To filter it to only the specified date category attribute, I added back in the where statement but receives the original error. Is there another wa to filter the response for only that specific date attribute? Thanks Again

Comment: No, I wasn't saying to remove the existing where condition; the case expression is in addition to that, not instead. But, if you're still seeing the error with the case expression (with or without the where - that might just mean you hit it sooner) then it sounds like you have string values that cannot be converted to dates, when you think they should be. Maybe in different formats, or maybe just rubbish. If you aren't on 12.2 yet (query v$version) then you can visually inspect all values without converting; or [write a function to identify them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14702163/266304).

Answer (score 0):

In the Given-case you cannot use one-simple-query which fits-all directly.

- you have to isolate-rows based on the resulting rows obtained from
  below query and perform update on those sets of rows to make them
  eligible dates either using substr, lpad or combination of both.
- building a complex "case" in single SQL query also

**Note** i've assumed column-name and table-name; Hope you get the Drift.

```
select length(value_char),count(1) 
    from your_table
        group by length(value_char);
```