# How to split and check the numerical date format (YYYYMMDD) in oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a col which stores the date, but it is in a numerical format in 8 digits (e.g.
20220613) how can I split it and check with the condition?

1. for the first 4 digits, I need to valid is it earlier than current year,
2. for the middle 2 digits, I need to valid is it between 01 - 12,
3. for the last 2 digits, I need base on the month to valid is it between 01 - 31 (e.g. if the the middle 2 digits (month) is 06, the last 2 digits can not greater than 31)

May I know that how to write this logic in oracle sql query? Thanks.

Comment: Date validation in Oracle itself may be tricky.  You may want to do this validation in your application layer.

Comment: to avoid unnecessary complications could you please check the datatype of the column

Comment: You should have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702050/valid-date-checks-in-oracle

Comment: What is the version of your Oracle database? Different options are available in different versions. Don't guess; run `select banner from v$version` and see what the first row says.

Answer (score 1):

Store it as a date data type to begin with. This means that the database understands the data - it can validate it for you, it knows that if you filter for rows with a date between 31st December 2021 and 1st January 2022 the range is only one day and not ~10000.

If you can’t do then then you can use [validate_conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD) to check the data type (remember to use the `FX` modifier in your format mask for an exact match). This function uses a string input so make sure you are converting your number to a string using an explicit format mask too.

As an example ;

```
SELECT VALIDATE_CONVERSION('20220631' AS DATE,'YYYYMMDD') FROM dual;
```

would return ***zero*** which indicates that the value is ***invalid*** as a *date*, while

```
SELECT VALIDATE_CONVERSION('20220613' AS DATE,'YYYYMMDD') FROM dual;
```

returns ***one*** which indicates that's a ***valid*** *date* value

If you can’t do that because you’re not running a recent version, create your own function which attempts the conversion using the desired format mask (again with `FX`) and handle the error.

Answer (score 1):

You should store date values using a `DATE` data type.

---

If you cannot (you should) then:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (col NUMBER(8));
```

Use a trigger and convert the value to a `DATE` and check it is before `SYSDATE`:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER table_name__col__trg
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF col ON table_name
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF TO_DATE(:NEW.col, 'YYYYMMDD') > SYSDATE THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Future date not allowed.');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Which works for:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (col) VALUES (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD'));
INSERT INTO table_name (col) VALUES (20220229);
```

But for:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (col) VALUES (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE + 1, 'YYYYMMDD'));
```

Gives the exception:

> ```
> ORA-20000: Future date not allowed.
> ```

And for:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (col) VALUES (20220229);
INSERT INTO table_name (col) VALUES (20200230);
```

Gives the exception:

> ```
> ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
> ```

---

If you just want dates that are before the current year then:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER table_name__col__trg
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF col ON table_name
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF TO_DATE(:NEW.col, 'YYYYMMDD') >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY') THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Only dates before this year allowed.');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

---

If you want it as a `SELECT` query rather than a constraint on the table then, from Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TO_DATE(col DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'YYYYMMDD') <= SYSDATE
```

*(Or `< TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY')` if you want the values from before this year.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b46a737907f44207d04a826fa2e6170c)*

Answer (score 0):

Your best option - by far - is to abandon idea of storing dates as anything else but `DATE` datatype. Whatever you do with your current model is just too much pain for no gain.

Anyway, here's one option for your current problem.

How to split that numeric value? Using the `substr` function. Then check whether each part of it is OK or not and - finally - if *all* of them are OK, then the whole value is OK.

```
SQL> select * from test order by id;

        ID      DATUM
---------- ----------
         1   20220613  -- wrong, because year isn't earlier than current year
         2   20220230  -- wrong, because February doesn't have 30 days
         3   20210524  -- OK

SQL> with temp as
  2    (select id, datum,
  3       case when substr(datum, 1, 4) < extract(year from sysdate) then 1 else 0 end year_ok,
  4       case when substr(datum, 5, 2) between 1 and 12 then 1 else 0 end month_ok,
  5       case when substr(datum, -2) between 1 and
  6                 to_char(last_day(to_date(substr(datum, 1, 6), 'yyyymm')), 'dd') then 1
  7            else 0 end day_ok
  8     from test
  9    )
 10  select id, datum,
 11    case when year_ok * month_ok * day_ok = 1 then 'OK' else 'Error' end status
 12  from temp
 13  order by id;

        ID      DATUM STATUS
---------- ---------- ------
         1   20220613 Error
         2   20220230 Error
         3   20210524 OK

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the logic to the following:

1. Check if is a date.
2. If it is a date, check that the year is < current year.

To check if a value is a date, use function `VALIDATE_CONVERSION` and to extract the year from the valid values, use `EXTRACT`.

Put it all together and this gives:

```
WITH test_data (dt_as_num) AS
(
SELECT 20210214 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20220613 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20212213 FROM DUAL
)
select dt_as_num ,
CASE WHEN 
  VALIDATE_CONVERSION(TO_CHAR(dt_as_num) AS DATE, 'YYYYMMDD', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') = 1 THEN
    CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(dt_as_num,'YYYYMMDD')) < EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) THEN 'ok'
    ELSE '> curr_year'
    END
  ELSE 'bad date'
END as result
from test_data;

DT_AS_NUM RESULT     
---------- -----------
  20210214 ok         
  20220613 > curr_year
  20212213 bad date
```

But of course, as everyone else states: Dates belong in columns of type `DATE`.